# Обрезать текст после достижения определенной высоты блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

может кто подсказать какими средствами можно реализовать ниже описанный пример
Есть некий блок с высотой 50vh, и соответственно высота этого блока меняется в зависимости от устройства. Также в этом блоке находится текст. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы на всех устройствах (при разных высотах блока) текст (при одинаковых размерах) не выходил за пределы блока

Answer (score 0):

для этого есть свойство overflow:hidden которое обрезает все что не входит в блок можно задать по осям (overflowX или overflowY)